# Must declare scalar variaable @ID when inserting record

Tags: c#, oledb

I am inserting a record in DB, I am using inline query, I have to get the generated ID, this is how I am doing this

```
 var query = "INSERT INTO [Users] ([Username],[Password])  VALUES(@username,@pwd) SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            OleDbParameter[] queryparam = new OleDbParameter[3];
            queryparam[0] = new OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar);
            queryparam[0].Value = "username";
            queryparam[1] = new OleDbParameter("@pwd", OleDbType.VarChar);
            queryparam[1].Value = "123456";
            queryparam[2] = new OleDbParameter("@ID", OleDbType.Integer);
            queryparam[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

             OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
              myCommand.Connection = DBConnectionHelper.getConnection();
                myCommand.CommandText = query;
                myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(queryparam);
                adapter.InsertCommand = myCommand;               
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

I also tried using `(int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar()` but no luck.

How can I get generated ID in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an [`OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) when [`CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to `Text`<sup>1</sup>. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
```

So, for your code your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ([Username],[Password]) VALUES(?,?) SELECT ? = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Which is the default, so is what your code is using.

Comment: how will I specify parameter values if I use ? ?

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi - did you read the page I linked to? The very next sentence after the quoted text and code is "Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text"

Comment: sorry let me check it now :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out of your question, you have declared a variable called `query` and written your query inside it. Also, your parameter declaration seems to be correct.

Now the problem might be in this line :

```
myCommand.CommandText = _query;
```

The variable is `query` and here you are using `_query`. So that is probably why the parameters are not added for that particular query and hence the error. It should be like this :

```
myCommand.CommandText = query;
```

Hope this clears.

Comment: that was typing error,I have corrected my question :) thanks for telling,but its not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Select Use Set @Id=Scope_Identity()

Comment: "INSERT INTO [Users] ([Username],[Password])  VALUES(@username,@pwd); SET@ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

Comment: please try like this after insert query add semicoln and after scope_identity();